# CreateProcess as Administrator and get its ProcessInformation Like ProcessID

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I need something like CreateProcess to run process as administrator, I haven't access on its manifest, also I need its ProcessID. I don't need to use runas with shell 'cause it won't give me the ProcessID.

If it's impossible so is there any function to check this?

[image: See this image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @HansPassant How?! Any example to run as administrator?

Comment: Example here, just supply Admin creds: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379608(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`ShellExecuteEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) with the `"runas"` verb to invoke UAC elevation.  You can specify the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag so the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.hProcess` field will receive the spawned process `HANDLE`.  You can query its process ID using [`GetProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215.aspx). Be sure to call [`CloseHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx) to close the returned `HANDLE` when you are done using it.